# Out-of-date screenshot on "Why is the system asking me to wait a day or more before asking another question?" Help Center page

Tags: bug, images, help-center, rate-limiting, screenshot

The beginning of the Help Center page "[Why is the system asking me to wait a day or more before asking another question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/asking-rate-limited)" currently looks like this:

> [image]

Could that screenshot be updated? It's... rather outdated.

It's a rather minor issue, but it'd be nice if it were fixed.